# How to fetch category page data inside component in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, contentful

I would like to create a category page containing all tags added to articles. When clicking on a tag it should show a page with all articles containing that specific tag.

I'm using Next.js, SSG, and fetching the articles from Contentful with the following GraphQL query:

```js
export async function getArticles() {
  const articlesQuery = gql`
    {
      articleCollection {
        items {
          title
          slug
          excerpt
          date
          contentfulMetadata {
            tags {
              name
              id
            }
          }
          featuredImage {
            title
            url
            width
            height
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `;
  return graphQLClient.request(articlesQuery);
}
```

The `contentfulMetadata` is where the tags come from:

```js
contentfulMetadata {
    tags {
        name
        id
    }
}
```

I've then created a `CategorySection` component:

```js
import styled from "styled-components";
import { getArticles } from "../../utils/contentful";
import Link from "next/link";

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const categories = await getArticles();

  return {
    props: {
      categories: categories.articleCollection.items,
    },
  };
}

export default function CategorySection({ categories }) {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <ContentWrapper>
        <CategoryWrapper>
          {categories.map((category) => {
            return (
              <Link href={`/articles/categories/${category.tags.name}`}>
                <Categories key={category.tags.id}>
                  {category.tags.name}
                </Categories>
              </Link>
            );
          })}
        </CategoryWrapper>
      </ContentWrapper>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

The `CategorySection` component gives me the following error message:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Below is my `/pages/articles/categories/[slug].jsx` file:

```js
import styled from "styled-components";
import { getArticles, getArticle } from "../../utils/contentful";

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const data = await getArticles();

  return {
    paths: data.articleCollection.items.map((article) => ({
      params: { slug: article.contentfulMetadata.tags.id },
    })),
    fallback: false,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const data = await getArticle(context.params.slug);

  return {
    props: { article: data.articleCollection.items[0] },
  };
}

export default function Category({ article }) {
  return <h1>{article.contentfulMetadata.tags.name}</h1>;
}
```

I'm getting the error below:

> Error: A required parameter (slug) was not provided as a string in
> getStaticPaths for /articles/categories/[slug]

Can you help me understand how I create dynamic pages from my categories (tags)?

Comment: @juliomalves thanks for letting me know that I can do better. I have updated the original post with more information, and I have read through the Next.js Pages docs.

Comment: The exact same code lies within my article page component, but as soon as I create a separate component, it gives me the error. Normally it would give me an array.

Comment: Wait, `CategorySection` is not a page then? If not, then you can't use `getStaticProps` in it. `getStaticProps` can only be used in page components. You'll need to fetch the data at the page level and pass it to the component where you want to use it.

Comment: You are brilliant! How would I get my GraphQL query in then?

Comment: You can either fetch the data server-side at the page level (with `getStaticProps`) and pass it down to the component, _OR_ fetch the data client-side in the component itself.

Comment: Okay. Can you provide an example of how I can pass it down to the component?

Comment: Seems like it will be solved with React Server Components soon. 

https://vercel.com/blog/everything-about-react-server-components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getStaticProps` can only be used in page components, so in your case it'll be completely ignored in your `CategorySection` component. You'll need to fetch the data at the page level and pass it to the component where you want to use it.

---

One possible solution is to simply pass the data as a prop down to the desired component.

```js
// pages/article

import { getArticles } from "../../utils/contentful";

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const categories = await getArticles();

    return {
        props: {
            categories: categories.articleCollection.items
        }
    };
}

export default function ArticlePage({ categories }) {
    return (
        <CategorySection categories={categories} />
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how would my CategorySection file look like?

Comment: The same as what you currently have, minus the `getStaticProps` function.

Comment: I got it to work. Thank you for providing the time to help me out.

Comment: Could you help med with the last piece of the puzzle? I have created a /pages/articles/[slug].jsx file and updated the original post.

Comment: I would suggest you create a new question as that's a different issue, and keep the scope of this question to your original issue. Questions should focus on a single problem only, to make it easier for everyone.